# Change colour and size to option box JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have to change the background colour and the size of the option box from JOptionPane.showInputDialog. Is it possible? Is it something included [in this list](http://thebadprogrammer.com/swing-uimanager-keys/)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are two ways you could try.

The first is using the UIManager and seeing if you can set the background of the JOptionPane that way.

The second is to use JOptionPane with a custom component that is designed to look (and feel) the way you want it, like

```
Component mySpecialDialog = ... // your dialog panel
JOption.showMessageDialog(null, mySpecialDialog);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with building brand new custom dialogs. Can you be more specific about the first option? Is there an actual option you could advice me?

Comment: For the first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html for the second, you just need to create a JPanel that looks the way your picture looks. Then you can show this in JOptionPane in the manner I demonstrated

Comment: I solved by changing the L&F to Windows. I will need to learn how to customize L&Fs someday. Thank you by the way.